# Achieve Play-cards like layout of controls in Android (Prototype image attached)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on board game based on playing cards, and following is the prototype what I'm supposed to achieve in the game.

[image: Protytype]

As you can see that 13 cards are stacked, now **each of the card is clickable and will respond to tap event**. The idea is that there will be empty 13 containers arranged in the above manner and when the cards are dealt, these containers will show the cards the player has received. So it needs to be dynamic. Restriction is that **I don't have any game engine used** and everything is based on standard Android widgets.

So the question is, can I achieve above layout exactly as in prototype image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is, can I achieve above layout exactly as in prototype image?

Yes.

How that can be achieved is for you to figure out. But here are some hints:

- It would be best to create the view hierarchy programatically rather than in an XML file for maximum compatibility with different screen sizes
- Take a look at [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)
- Margins can take negative values

Comment: Thanks, obviously hints are enough, I just wanted to know if my design is practical or not.